# What does \specialsection do in amsart.cls?

Tags: amsart

In the documentation of `amsart`. [*AMS Author Handbook: Journal Classes*](https://mirror.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf), it is said that

> `\specialsection` differs from`\section` mainly in the
> formatting of the heading.

It is listed between `\part` and `\section`.

Grätzer said in his *More Math into LaTeX* (4ed and 5ed) that:

> There is also the seldom used top level `\specialsection` command.
> Articles do not have parts and chapters, but sometimes a long article
> may require further division using the `\specialsection` command.

However, `\part` is defined in the `amsart.cls`, as other document classes (such as `article.cls`) do. And I notice that `\specialsection` shares the same counter with `\section`, and the typesetting formats of the two commands are rather similar (a little difference in fonts and spacing).

```
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\centering}}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
```

So I wonder how it is used.

BTW, the commented source code of AMS classes ([amsclass.pdf](https://texdoc.org/serve/amsclass/0)) says that

> Specialsection correlates to our inhouse Z-head.

And I think it is also difficult to understand.

Comment: I guess that particular in-house styles redefine `\specialsection`, possibly not to have a number, but, indeed, the documentation is not very clear.

Comment: the documentation is not only not very clear, but clearly wrong regarding `\part`.  i shall investigate, but may not be able to find anything definitive, the perpetrators being either deceased or long gone from ams.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation file *Instructions for Preparation of Papers and Monographs AMS-LaTeX* (`instrl.pdf`) is woefully out of date, and about to be discarded.

New documentation has been created in the form of three author handbooks, for journal articles ([AMS Author Handbook, Journal Classes](http://www.ams.org/tex/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf)), monographs and textbooks, and proceedings articles (links to all from [this web page](http://www.ams.org/tex/author-handbook)).

In the journals handbook, headings are covered on page 13, but not much detail is given.  here are the salient differences:

- `\part` is set in bold and numbered, although the number (for some unexplained
  reason) is normal weight.
- `\section` is numbered and set in small caps (except for properly identified
  math).
- `\specialsection` is numbered (with the same counter as `\section`) and set
  in the normal font, but content remains in upper- and lowercase as input.

For journal articles, none of these headings are re-used as running heads, so short forms (although provided for `\part` and `\section`) are not used.

It will take a while for these handbooks to reach CTAN and TeX Live as part of the `amscls` collection, owing to the manner of their compilation (multiple source files with conditional inclusion of relevant segments) and the TeX Live requirement for inclusion of source code.  When installed there, the `instrl` files will be removed.